# Batch File to Delete Specific Subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have three directories, and each of these directories contains 8 subdirectories, and each of those subdirectories contains 2 folders that I want to delete.

The structure:

[Edited the path-name]

```
C:/Process/CIM
             /AB_CIM
                    /LOG
                    /DATA
             /CC_CIM
                    /LOG
                    /DATA
             /CIM_RD
                    ...
           ...

C:/Process/DIM
             /AB_DIM
                    /LOG
                    /DATA
             /CC_DIM
                    /LOG
                    /DATA
             /DIM_RD
                    ...
             ...

C:/Process/RRS
             ...
```

So basically I want to remove `LOG` and `DATA` in all of those subdirectories. I thought of doing this using two separate batch files***:

The first batch file would contain:

```
call secondBatchFile.cmd CIM
call secondBatchFile.cmd DIM
call secondBatchFile.cmd RRS
```

Now, I'm not sure how to write the second batch file since those subdirectories have different names (but a common part: AB_*, CC_*, *_RD, etc). I was wondering if someone could help me with it.

Thanks for your help in advance.

*** The reason for doing this using two separate batch files is that I might sometimes need to keep `LOG` and `DATA` for one of the parent directories (e.g. CIM), so this way I can just comment out only one line of the first batch file and then run it.

Comment: Is it DOS batch or NT script?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as it would be possible to run the batch file on Windows XP, but DOS batch is preferable.

Comment: It matters for the answer, as NT scripting allows for way more sophisticated constructs. I'll check back from home where I have an XP VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you're confident that LOG and DATA folders in other directories won't be picked up.  Comment out the actual delete in the code below and review the `.dat` file output before executing.

```
REM Output all LOG and DATA sub-directories into corresponding DAT files
dir /ad/s/b log* > log_directories.dat
dir /ad/s/b data* > data_directories.dat

REM remove every entry listed in log_directories.dat
for /f %%i in (log_directories.dat) do rd/s %%i

REM remove every entry listed in data_directories.dat
for /f %%i in (data_directories.dat) do rd/s %%i
```

If you run this from `C:`, you're probably going to get directories you don't want.  But assuming all of your targets are grouped under a dedicated sub-directory (and assuming you run the `.bat` from that dedicated directory), this won't be a problem.

And by default, this solution gives you your desired log of which directories it will be deleting (log will be overwritten for each run though).

Comment: @AminoAcid, can you comment on whether this solution meets your needs?

Comment: There's only one problem with this code. In case I would want to keep the data and the logs for a specific process, I won't be able to do it using this method.

Comment: @AminoAcid, if you mean that you'd want to be more specific about which directories you delete, yes, you could.  I didn't include code for that because you seemed to prefer the method of editing a log file for that.  If you need to be more specific... you need to be more specific.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I thought you were suggesting a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

If the 8 sub-folders are always the same pattern, i.e. `AB_*, CC_*, *_RD,` etc, the second batch file could be something like:

```
cd C:\%1%

rmdir AB_%1%\LOG
rmdir AB_%1%\DATA

rmdir CC_%1%\LOG
rmdir CC_%1%\DATA

rmdir %1%_RD\LOG
rmdir %1%_RD\DATA
...

cd c:\
```